# scikit learn says num samples must be greater than num clusters

Tags: scikit-learn

Using sklearn.cluster.KMeans. Nearly this exact code worked earlier, all I changed was the way I built my dataset. I have just no idea where even to start... Here's the code:

```
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
km = KMeans(n_clusters=20)
for item in dfX:
    if type(item) != type(dfX[0]):
        print(item)
print(len(dfX))
print(dfX[:10])
km.fit(dfX)
print(km.cluster_centers_)
```

Which outputs the following:

```
12147
[1.201, 1.237, 1.092, 1.074, 0.979, 0.885, 1.018, 1.083, 1.067, 1.071]
/home/sbendl/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py:386: DeprecationWarning: Passing 1d arrays as data is deprecated in 0.17 and willraise ValueError in 0.19. Reshape your data either using X.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or X.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.
  DeprecationWarning)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/sbendl/PycharmProjects/MLFP/K-means.py", line 20, in <module>
    km.fit(dfX)
  File "/home/sbendl/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/cluster/k_means_.py", line 812, in fit
    X = self._check_fit_data(X)
  File "/home/sbendl/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/cluster/k_means_.py", line 789, in _check_fit_data
    X.shape[0], self.n_clusters))
ValueError: n_samples=1 should be >= n_clusters=20

Process finished with exit code 1
```

As you can see from the output, there are definitely 12147 samples, which is greater than 20 in most counting systems ;). Additionally they're all floats, so it couldn't be having a problem with that. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Get rid of that looping-print and use numpy to analyze (instead of for x loops and len). Print out the shape of dfX and you will see it's probably (1, 12147), which is 1 sample of dim 12147 according to sklearn.

Comment: ^Yep. That was it, I was wondering why I had done it like that before xD

Comment: Does this answer your question? [KMeans clustering - Value error: n\_samples=1 should be >= n\_cluster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54833924/kmeans-clustering-value-error-n-samples-1-should-be-n-cluster)

Comment: @MohitGaikwad possibly it would have 6 years ago

Comment: @bendl could you please check out last answer, because that worked for me.