# KMeans clustering - Value error: n_samples=1 should be >= n_cluster

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, k-means

I am doing an experiment with three time-series datasets with different characteristics for my experiment whose format is as the following.

```
    0.086206438,10
    0.086425551,12
    0.089227066,20
    0.089262508,24
    0.089744425,30
    0.090036815,40
    0.090054172,28
    0.090377569,28
    0.090514071,28
    0.090762872,28
    0.090912691,27
```

The first column is a `timestamp`. For reproducibility reasons, I am sharing the data [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=18SdS6NUX3ff334A6G-lJOJYDCppiZaZD). From column 2, I wanted to read the current row and compare it with the value of the previous row. If it is greater, I keep comparing. If the current value is smaller than the previous row's value, I want to divide the current value (smaller) by the previous value (larger). Accordingly, here is the code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

protocols = {}

types = {"data1": "data1.csv", "data2": "data2.csv", "data3": "data3.csv"}

for protname, fname in types.items():
    col_time,col_window = np.loadtxt(fname,delimiter=',').T
    trailing_window = col_window[:-1] # "past" values at a given index
    leading_window  = col_window[1:]  # "current values at a given index
    decreasing_inds = np.where(leading_window < trailing_window)[0]
    quotient = leading_window[decreasing_inds]/trailing_window[decreasing_inds]
    quotient_times = col_time[decreasing_inds]

    protocols[protname] = {
        "col_time": col_time,
        "col_window": col_window,
        "quotient_times": quotient_times,
        "quotient": quotient,
    }

    plt.figure(); plt.clf()
    plt.plot(quotient_times,quotient, ".", label=protname, color="blue")
    plt.ylim(0, 1.0001)
    plt.title(protname)
    plt.xlabel("time")
    plt.ylabel("quotient")
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()
```

And this produces the following three points - one for each [dataset](https://drive.google.com/open?id=18SdS6NUX3ff334A6G-lJOJYDCppiZaZD) I shared.

[image]
[image]
[image]

As we can see from the points in the plots based on the code given above, `data1` is pretty consistent whose value is around 1, `data2` will have two quotients (whose values will concentrate either around 0.5 or 0.8) and the values of `data3` are concentrated around two values (either around 0.5 or 0.7). This way, given a new data point (with `quotient` and `quotient_times`), I want to know which `cluster` it belongs to by building each dataset stacking these two transformed features `quotient` and `quotient_times`. I am trying it with `KMeans` clustering as the following

```
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
k_means = KMeans(n_clusters=3, random_state=0)
k_means.fit(quotient)
```

But this is giving me an error: `ValueError: n_samples=1 should be >= n_clusters=3`. How can we fix this error?

Update: samlpe quotient data = `array([ 0.7       ,  0.7       ,  0.4973262 ,  0.7008547 ,  0.71287129,
        0.704     ,  0.49723757,  0.49723757,  0.70676692,  0.5       ,
        0.5       ,  0.70754717,  0.5       ,  0.49723757,  0.70322581,
        0.5       ,  0.49723757,  0.49723757,  0.5       ,  0.49723757])`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As is, your `quotient` variable is now *one single* sample; here I get a different error message, probably due to different Python/scikit-learn version, but the essence is the same:

```
import numpy as np
quotient = np.array([ 0.7 , 0.7 , 0.4973262 , 0.7008547 , 0.71287129, 0.704 , 0.49723757, 0.49723757, 0.70676692, 0.5 , 0.5 , 0.70754717, 0.5 , 0.49723757, 0.70322581, 0.5 , 0.49723757, 0.49723757, 0.5 , 0.49723757])
quotient.shape
# (20,)

from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
k_means = KMeans(n_clusters=3, random_state=0)
k_means.fit(quotient)
```

This gives the following error:

```
ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:
array=[0.7        0.7        0.4973262  0.7008547  0.71287129 0.704
 0.49723757 0.49723757 0.70676692 0.5        0.5        0.70754717
 0.5        0.49723757 0.70322581 0.5        0.49723757 0.49723757
 0.5        0.49723757].
Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.
```

which, despite the different wording, is not different from yours - essentially it says that your data look like a single sample.

Following the first advice(i.e. considering that `quotient` contains a single *feature* (column) resolves the issue:

```
k_means.fit(quotient.reshape(-1,1))
# result
KMeans(algorithm='auto', copy_x=True, init='k-means++', max_iter=300,
    n_clusters=3, n_init=10, n_jobs=None, precompute_distances='auto',
    random_state=0, tol=0.0001, verbose=0)
```

Answer (score 2):

Please try the code below. A brief explanation on what I've done:

First I built the dataset `sample = np.vstack((quotient_times, quotient)).T` and  standardized it, so it would become easier to cluster. Following, I've applied `DBScan` with multiple hyperparameters (eps and min_samples) until I've found the one that separated the points better. Finally, I've plotted the data with its respective labels, since you are working with 2 dimensional data, it's easy to visualize how good the clustering is.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.cluster import DBSCAN
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

types = {"data1": "data1.csv", "data2": "data2.csv", "data3": "data3.csv"}

dataset = np.empty((0, 2))

for protname, fname in types.items():
    col_time,col_window = np.loadtxt(fname,delimiter=',').T

    trailing_window = col_window[:-1] # "past" values at a given index
    leading_window  = col_window[1:]  # "current values at a given index
    decreasing_inds = np.where(leading_window < trailing_window)[0]
    quotient = leading_window[decreasing_inds]/trailing_window[decreasing_inds]
    quotient_times = col_time[decreasing_inds]

    sample = np.vstack((quotient_times, quotient)).T
    dataset = np.append(dataset, sample, axis=0)

scaler = StandardScaler()
dataset = scaler.fit_transform(dataset)

k_means = DBSCAN(eps=0.6, min_samples=1)
k_means.fit(dataset)

colors = [i for i in k_means.labels_]

plt.figure();
plt.title('Dataset 1,2,3')
plt.xlabel("time")
plt.ylabel("quotient")
plt.scatter(dataset[:, 0], dataset[:, 1], c=colors)
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: thank you, you are awesome. but why do we have negative quotients? It should be a number between 0 and 1. Is it also possible to plot 3 of them in one figure so that we can see how the cluster looks.

Comment: I'ts because I've applied the `scaler.fit_transform(dataset)` snippet. If you want to know more about it, please refer to [Feature scaling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_scaling). It's definitely possible, you just have to combine all the datasets before applying DBScan.

Answer (score -1):

You are trying to make 3 clusters, while you have only 1 np.array i.e n_samples.

1. Try increasing the no. of arrays.
2. Decreasing no. of clusters.
3. Reshaping the array (not sure)