# Clustering 1 variable scatter plot

Tags: pandas, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis

[image][image]

I would like to cluster this scatter plot (y axis is the density measured and the x axis is the time).
Is there any way to get the points highlighted in red in the picture? Does it make sense in this case to use a clustering algorithm?

Below is the code:

```
df = pd.read_csv(path, sep=';', decimal=",", low_memory=False, skiprows=1).drop(['Session ID'], axis=1)
df = df.iloc[17120:]

print(df.head())
#print(len(df.index))

#df_len = np.arange(len(df.index))


dens = df['Density']
dens = dens.astype(float)
print(dens.dtypes)
start_dens = 78800+6000
dens_sub = dens[start_dens:]
x = np.arange(1,len(dens_sub)+1)
plt.plot(dens_sub)
plt.ylim([1040,1070])
plt.show()

plt.scatter(x, dens_sub)
plt.ylim([1050,1062])

X = x, dens_sub


wccs = []
for i in range(1,11):
    kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=i, max_iter=100)
    kmeans.fit(X)
    wccs.append(kmeans.inertia_)
```

I get "ValueError: n_samples=2 should be >= n_clusters=3." What am I missing? [image]

Comment: Are you correctly formulating your X sample for KMeans? It seems to interpret X as 2 samples, namely x and dens_sub, then fail when your loop increment i reaches value 3.

Comment: Prior questions and publications exist on the theme of "**time series** clustering". Is none of them helping?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [KMeans clustering - Value error: n\_samples=1 should be >= n\_cluster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54833924/kmeans-clustering-value-error-n-samples-1-should-be-n-cluster)

Answer (score 0):

I had a go at clustering with synthetic data - see below for example results and code. Generally poor results, but perhaps the DBSCAN attempt yielded usable results. This is partly down to my suboptimal tuning of the algorithms - you may get better results with thorough and systematic tuning. I interpreted both time and y as features, and clustering was performed in that space.

[image]
[image]

An alternative approach might be to generate a spectrogram from the data. It might be more feasible to cluster in that time-frequency space, zero out the non-signal clusters, and apply an inverse transform to the remainder. The signal in the data looks like it's mainly around some fundamental frequency.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#
# Synthesise test date
#
np.random.seed(24052023)
noise_time = np.arange(0, 500)
noise = np.random.uniform(low=1050, high=1062, size=len(noise_time))

signal_time = np.arange(0, 500)
signal = 1055 + (
    np.sin(2 * np.pi * 0.01 * signal_time) / (0.6 + 1e-3*signal_time)
   + 0.6 * np.sin(2 * np.pi * np.random.rand(len(signal_time)) * signal_time)
    )

merged_time = np.arange(0, 500, 0.5)
interp_signal = np.interp(merged_time, signal_time, signal)
interp_signal[::2] = np.nan

interp_noise = np.interp(merged_time, noise_time, noise)
interp_noise[1::2] = np.nan

noised = np.nansum(np.c_[interp_signal[:, None], interp_noise[:, None]], axis=1)

#Put time and measurements into a matrix
# one row per sample & one column per feature
all_data = np.stack([merged_time, noised], axis=1)

#
# Plot the noise, signal, and the noised signal
#
f, axs = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(10, 2), sharey=True, layout='constrained')
axs[0].scatter(merged_time, interp_noise, label='noise')
axs[0].scatter(merged_time, interp_signal, color='red', label='signal')
axs[1].scatter(merged_time, noised, color='maroon', label='noised')
f.legend(ncol=3, loc='upper right')

#
# Preprocess the data
#
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

scaler = StandardScaler().fit(all_data)
X = scaler.transform(all_data)

#
# Try different clustering algorithms & plot
#
from sklearn.cluster import (
    KMeans, AgglomerativeClustering,
    HDBSCAN, DBSCAN, MeanShift,
    AffinityPropagation, SpectralClustering,
    OPTICS
)

kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=3).fit(X)

f, axs = plt.subplots(4, 2, figsize=(10, 10), sharex=True, sharey=True)

for i, clusterer in enumerate([KMeans(n_clusters=5, n_init='auto'),
                               AgglomerativeClustering(n_clusters=4),
                               HDBSCAN(alpha=2, allow_single_cluster=True, min_cluster_size=10),
                               DBSCAN(eps=0.2, min_samples=13),
                               MeanShift(bandwidth=0.8, bin_seeding=True),
                               AffinityPropagation(damping=0.9854),
                               SpectralClustering(n_clusters=15),
                               OPTICS(min_samples=15)]
                              ):
    clusters = clusterer.fit(X).labels_
    ax = axs.flatten()[i]
    ax.scatter(merged_time, noised, c=clusters, cmap='Set1')
    ax.set_title(str(type(clusterer)).split('.')[-1][:-2])
    
for ax in axs.flatten():
    ax.axis('off')
f.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.5)
```

Comment: Updated clustering to consider both time and y, leading to an improvement in some results.